# Resize relative div if parent absolute div change height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The absolute div gets a new height of 800. How to auto resize the relative container?

```css
.relative {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #111;
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">  
  
<div class="absolute"> 
</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: how would the `absolute` div change height?

Comment: For example here: http://printnil.com/products/angebotsmappe?variant=1023645719 click on "Jetzt Angebot anfordern"

Answer (score 0):

Positioned elements are removed from the normal flow of the document, so changing their size won't alter the height of their parent.

However, even if they are bigger than their ancestors, you can still see them thanks to `overflow`.

In your case, remove

```css
.st-container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.st-content {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Then, it will still be become the default `overflow: visible`, so you absolute element will still be visible (overflowing), so you will be able to use page's scrollbar to see it fully.

```js
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('absolute').style.height
  = document.getElementById('relative').clientHeight*2 + 'px'
};
```

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#relative {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #111;
}
#absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #aaf;
}
```

```html
<div id="relative">  
  <div id="absolute">
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="Change size" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Oriol stated you shouldn't be using `position: absolute` because it removes the element from the flow of the document thus won't register a `height`. What you can do instead if you are looking for an example like the line you posted is have a container set to `display: none` and use jquery's `slideDown` (or `slideToggle` if you want the container to show and hide):

**HTML**

```
<button>Click Me</button>

<div class="info">
   <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

   <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.info{
  display: none;
  background: black;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

**JS**

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $(".info").slideDown();
  $(this).hide(); //the example you used hid the button after clicking
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wc51o8mj/)